# Google calendar api saves dates as UTC and not local

Tags: timezone, google-calendar-api, .net-6.0

I am developing an app with an API, via which you can create an event in a google calendar. The issue I have is that the date of the event (which is correctly added) is not using my Timzone (Brussels) but UTC.

So if I want to create an event at 8:45 in my Timzone, it's saved as 6:45 in my calendar.

This is the code I actually have :

```
var reservation = new Event
{
    Summary = GenerateReservationSummary(reservationInput, selectedCares),
    Start = new EventDateTime
    {
        DateTimeDateTimeOffset = reservationInput.ReservationDate,
        TimeZone = TimeZone // string set as "Europe/Brussels"
    },
    End = new EventDateTime
    {
        DateTimeDateTimeOffset = GetEndDateTime(reservationInput.ReservationDate, selectedCares),
        TimeZone = TimeZone
    },
    Reminders = null // No reminders
};
```

When debugging, I was able to ensure that the `ReservationDate` was actually set at 8:45, which is the case, and `DateTimeKind` is also set at `Local`.

I tried multiple things such as the followings, but none of them worked.

```
new DateTimeOffset(date, TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
new DateTimeOffset(date, TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset(date))
```

What am I missing ?

Also, I use an Angular front-end app with the form that is sent to the API, and I have the right date in my angular component, but it is sent as UTC in the api call payload. What's the best way to fix my issue (front or back) ?

Thanks !

Comment: by default it saves it to that of the calendar itself.

Comment: The solution was so simple..Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the time of an event uses the timezone of the calendar itself.

So by setting the timezone when you create the event you tend to end up confusing things a little.